# How to open an activity with its progress by clicking on the notification

Tags: java, android

```
Intent open = new Intent(this, WorkoutActivity.class);
PendingIntent openContent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, open, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

String nDistance = Double.toString(lastDistance);
String nSpeed = String.valueOf(speed);
NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_logo_round)
            .setContentTitle(sWorkoutName.getText())
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Distance Covered : " + nDistance + " Kms" + '\n' + "Time : " + time + '\n' + "Speed : " + nSpeed + " km/hr"))
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setContentIntent(openContent);

notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());
```

Hi I am a beginner in app development and I need some help.
I am trying to open workout activity when I click on the notification. But when I do that, the activity is starting from the beginning all of its progress is lost.
So what can i do to open an activity with its progress when i click on a notification?

Comment: Try learning about the [launch modes](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-android-activity-launch-modes-49ec89ef79d2) ,[android launch modes](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-launch-mode-787d28952959) and use them in your Manifest file. This will solve your issue

Comment: If you solve your issue, you can self-answer to explain how you solve it

Answer (score 0):

Change the launch mode for that specific activity that you want to open with the current progress in the manifest file
Learn about Android launch mode here : https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-android-activity-launch-modes-49ec89ef79d2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).